# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nextTimeLabel.'

Tags: ios

I get this error while trying to load data into my cells using a custom cell:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x8d61570> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nextTimeLabel.'
```

I read some of the solutions here regarding this error. I know it is some issue with an deleted IBOutlet , so i did the following:

1. removed all connections and connected again with new views
2. deleted the xib file entirely and changed the names of the xib file and the subviews
3. I looked in the whole project(including the source file of the xib) for "nextTimeLabel" - nothing.

4.Quiting simulator/deleting the app/ clearing content

EDIT. code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BNRCellView" bundle:nil];

    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BNRCells"]; //lets try to change that later

}

#pragma mark - TableView Data source methods

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BNRCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BNRCells" ];
    NSDictionary *dic = self.courses[indexPath.row];
    cell.courseNameLabel.text= dic[@"title"];


    return cell;
}
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just post a code that throws this error.

Comment: Search on the error. There are countless existing discussions on the topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Answer (score 0):

In the `BNRCellView` XIB for this cell (with registered identifier `BNRCells`), somewhere you have an outlet named `nextTimeLabel` connected to something which would seem to have the wrong class (an `NSObject` instance rather than what should presumably be a controller or view instance).

Check all of your class name settings and any outlet connections to the file owner.